# pymysql warning: 1300 invalid utf8 character string: 'FFD8FF' when upload image to database

Tags: python, pymysql

When inserting the image to the database, an error occours:

```
/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:329: 
Warning: (1300, u"Invalid utf8 character string: 'FFD8FF'")
  self._do_get_result()
```

I cannot understand what it means

Comment: It always return 'FFD8FF' Error

Comment: Are you trying to store a jpg image "binary" data into a VARCHAR column?

Comment: Np but a jpg image binary data in to a LONGBLOB column, might that be the problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36849144/how-to-avoid-encoding-warning-when-inserting-binary-data-into-a-blob-column-in-m